# Oracle: list user-created tables in the SYS schema

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, metadata, system-tables

I need to delete all tables (hundreds) in the SYS schema that someone accidentally created with sqlplus. Looking in `dba_tables` and `dba_objects`, I don't see a way to distinguish these tables from pre-existing stock system tables. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most tables in SYS schema are created when database is installed. You probably know approximately when the new tables were created, so query like this should work:

```
select *
from dba_objects
where object_type='TABLE'
  and owner='SYS'
  and created > <date before new tables were created>;
```

Comment: I noticed this solution, it's just surprising that there is not more definitive metadata on this.

Comment: Probably because all tables in SYS schema are assumed to be system tables